# Is there any way for saving the content

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

Is there a way in firefox developer tools or in google chrome devtools to save to a file the ascii content of one of the tab shown by the tools, such us Elements, Console and so on?

Comment: In Chrome you can open devtools-on-devtools: detach the main devtools panel into a floating window, focus it, press the hotkey to invoke devtools (Ctrl-Shift-i in Windows). This second devtools can inspect the first (main) one and you can use element picker to choose the panel, then run `copy($0.textContent)` in console.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that in both browsers, they just have two different ways to achieve that:

## Firefox

1. Open the DevTools.
2. Switch to the Settings panel.
3. Under *Advanced settings* check the options *Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging toolboxes* and *Enable remote debugging*.
4. Open the Browser Toolbox (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or Firefox Menu > *Web Developer* > *Browser Toolbox*).
5. In the Browser Toolbox enable the element picker.
6. Click the element within the DevTools, which you want to copy.
7. a) To copy the HTML structure, right click the element and choose *Copy* > *Outer HTML*.
   b) To copy the text content, switch to the Console panel and execute `copy($0.textContent)`.

## Chrome

1. Open the DevTools.
2. Detach them into a separate window.
3. Focus the window.
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to open a second DevTools window.
5. In that second DevTools window enable the element picker.
6. Click the element within the DevTools, which you want to copy.
7. a) To copy the HTML structure, right click the element and choose *Copy* > *Copy Element*.
   b) To copy the text content, switch to the Console panel and execute `copy($0.textContent)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can consert your content to [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) then to [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static) which is downlodable.

Example code is given at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/76298535/1762051