# How to create and save file in developer tools console of google chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, filesystems, google-chrome-devtools

```
var data = "my sample data string"

// Lets write this data to filesystem as data.txt
```

I could not find anything relevant on
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/

Is there any way to create and save file right inside from [console](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/api/) in [developer tools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/) in [google chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome)?

Comment: Object.assign(document.createElement('a'), {download: 'data.txt', href: URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]))}).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))

Answer (score 1):

Its possible by converting string to [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) then to [object url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL_static)

```js
// Convert string data to url
var data = "my sample data string"
let blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'text/plain'})
let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)

// Create anchor tag
let downloadLink = document.createElement('a')
downloadLink.download = 'myFile.txt'
downloadLink.href = url

// Click to download file
downloadLink.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy approach is use `copy()` in devtools console.

```js
var data = "my sample data string"
copy(data)
```

or just right click on object to see copy option.

Now this data is available in clipboard so just paste it.

Answer (score -2):

[image: DevTools - SaveAs]

You can simply use the right mouse button => Save as which will create a file containing console log.